# use a variable as a variable

Tags: bash, eval

I'd like to use a variable `variablenaam` for using in a loop.
I tried for hours but can't make it work.

My experiment in bash on a RPi 4 with the latest Raspbian.

I like to make the use of xstack1 and xstack2 variable so i can use them in a loop. Example below has two stacks I like to use in a loop
so I have to make the variable `xstack<value>  variable`.

```
clear
xstack1=( domoticz dashboard dashticz nodered )
xstack2=( x y z )
printf "Original value xstack1[*]= ${xstack1[*]}"   # this gives all the entries of x, this must be the result at the end by choose for xstack1 = q=1

printf "\n\n Lets Start, try to make xstack variable"
q=1                     # we want tot retrieve all values of xstack1
qq=$(eval "echo xstack${q}") 
printf "\nvariablenaame of xstack1 = $qq"   # so far so good
printf "\n"


qqq=$(eval "echo $qq[*]")           #now add the all parameter
printf "\nvariablenaam with wildcard must do show all values but dont= $qqq"  #only one value
printf "\n\n"

qqqq=$(eval "echo \$$qqq")
printf "last try and does not work, i only get one value= ${qqqq}\n"
```

This is The code where i want to use it. you see for similar block with stack1-4 and i think this can be one block with a variable name for xstack1-4. This xstack is a array and i think that gives the problem. These blocks are working perfectly, but not written perfectly :-)

```
local t_maxkolom=9
local t_mitem=1
local t_stack=0
while [ $t_stack -lt $t_maxkolom ]
do  

    local t_gitem=0
    local t_sp='%31s'


    if [ -z "${stack1[$t_stack]}" ]; then printf $t_sp && printf "${normal}"; else
        printf "${number}  $((t_mitem + $t_gitem )))${normal} Toevoegen " && printf '%-16s' "${stack1[$t_stack]}" && printf "${normal}"
    fi

    local t_sp='%32s'
    local t_gitem=$((t_gitem + 10))

    if [ -z "${stack2[$t_stack]}" ]; then printf $t_sp && printf "${normal}"; else
        printf "${number}  $((t_mitem + $t_gitem )))${normal} Toevoegen " && printf '%-16s' "${stack2[$t_stack]}" && printf "${normal}"
    fi

    local t_sp='%32s'
    local t_gitem=$((t_gitem + 10))

    if [ -z "${stack3[$t_stack]}" ]; then printf $t_sp && printf "${normal}"; else
        printf "${number}  $((t_mitem + $t_gitem )))${normal} Toevoegen " && printf '%-16s' "${stack3[$t_stack]}" && printf "${normal}"
    fi

    local t_sp='%32s'
    local t_gitem=$((t_gitem + 10))

    if [ -z "${stack4[$t_stack]}" ]; then printf $t_sp && printf "${normal}\n"; else
        printf "${number}  $((t_mitem + $t_gitem )))${normal} Toevoegen " && printf '%-16s' "${stack4[$t_stack]}" && printf "${normal}"
    printf "\n"
    fi

    t_stack=$(( $t_stack + 1 ))
    t_mitem=$((t_mitem + 1))
done
```

With this code I generate the menu items for my docker app

[image]

Comment: You want to use variable `variablenaam`, but in your code you have `printf "\nvariablenaame` - is it a typo on the code or in the question?

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397). It's hard to read and impossible to copy for testing possible solutions to help you

Comment: The Bash command you want is `declare -n myRef`, which declares a `nameref` variable. Then you can loop through the iterations like `for j in {0..9}; do myRef="stack${j]"; ...` and have "${myRef}" reference each stack in turn.

Comment: Don't.  You might think variable indirection is a good idea, but it really isn't.  Use an indexed array or, probably better, an associative array instead.   Even better, if you're trying to do something in shell that's complex enough to even consider using variable indirection then you should be using a better language instead - perl or python, for example, perhaps awk, or pretty nearly any language that isn't shell.

Answer (score 0):

By example this ...

```
xstack1=( domoticz dashboard dashticz nodered )
xstack2=( x y z )

q=1
declare -n qq="xstack${q}"
qqq="${qq[*]}"
echo "q=[$q]"
echo "qq=[$qq]"
echo "qqq=[$qqq]"
```

produces this

```
q=[1]
qq=[domoticz]
qqq=[domoticz dashboard dashticz nodered]
```

You must declare the nameref to an array explicitly.